# Why is the CPU usage so high in Firefox when using CSS3 animation property?

Tags: html, css

Today I was going to make a couple of keyframe animations using CSS. I'm using the following CSS:

```
-webkit-animation: ballanim 5.6s infinite;
     -o-animation: ballanim 5.6s infinite;
        animation: ballanim 5.6s infinite;
```

There is a big problem though, and I don't know if it's a problem with my code or if it is a Firefox problem. For comparison, on 10X of these animations:

- Safari: 12.8% CPU usage.
- Firefox: over 70% CPU usage.

I uploaded my webpage here:

http://hkwh01.99k.org/test/services.html

Is Firefox not suitable for CSS animations? Does anybody know the reason for this? Should I think of another method to do animations?

Comment: Well, when I entered "firefox css animation" into Google, the first result that popped up was "firefox css animation performance", so it may very well not be suitable for CSS animations. Have you looked through the aforementioned google results?

Comment: My Firefox eats only 2% of CPU Q6600 on your page.

Comment: really ? lol why it eats 99% of mine?

Comment: CSS animations are designed to be hardware accelerated. Which in practice means it will heavily depend on your graphic card and drivers and how the browser call it.

Comment: 83% CPU on FF 17.0.1 OS 10.8.2

Comment: Will FireFox going to fix this problem? Do they even know?

Comment: Ubuntu here. 30% for FF and 65% for Chromium...

Comment: 10% vs 0% in chrome on win 8

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.10 using Chrome 23, I'm getting 65--70% cpu usage.

Answer (score 4):

CSS animations are supposed to be hardware (GPU) accelerated.

Look at this really evil example http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Performance/Chalkboard/
 and compare performance of IE10 (native HWA by default) and other browsers (no HWA by default, currently). Then - enable HWA, and see how much better other browsers perform second time (but still worse than IE10).

Until the time, when all your target browsers will support HWA by default, you should not rely on animations for non-essential features. And its probably a good idea to disable animations for them.

Comment: +1. Here is another great example for using CSS3 animations, and that these can cause high CPU usage when not using HWA: http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/9132/sun-rise.html.